# create video file from ajax provided dataURI

Tags: javascript, php, webrtc

Okay, I've read at least a hundred articles on this, and I can find no clear example to do what I'm trying to do, exactly. I'm using RecordRTC to get my videos. I can get the webm data URI for the video in the form of `blob:http://www.example.com/be1b2fdd-af19-4a10-b8ef-7a56a1087e3c`. I know I can basically feed this source (used for my video element) to a canvas element, and then get an encoded dataURI with the canvas `toDataURL()` method. However, seeing that the encoded data should be a video, using a parameter such as `video/webm` for `toDataURL()` still returns an encoded string for the `image/png` mimetype. My question is this: if I pass the blob url (`blob:http://www.example.com/be1b2fdd-af19-4a10-b8ef-7a56a1087e3c`) to PHP, how can I create the webm file on my server's filesystem? If this isn't possible, how can I create an encoded string for the `video/webm` mimetype from the canvas?

This is my video class object:

```
var Video = {
    eId: '',
    element: {},
    source: {},
    RtcOpts: {video: true, audio: true},
    RTC: {},
    media: {},
    init: function(elementId){
        Video.eId = elementId;
        Video.media = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    },
    success: function(stream){
        Video.RTC = new MRecordRTC(stream);
        Video.element = document.getElementById(Video.eId);

        if(window.webkitURL || window.URL){
            Video.source = (window.webkitURL) ? window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream) : window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }else{
            Video.source = stream;
        }

        Video.element.autoplay = true;
        Video.element.src = Video.source;
        Video.RTC.startRecording();
        Video.element.play();
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.error('getUserMedia Error', e);
    },
    stop: function(){
        Video.RTC.stopRecording(function(WebMURL){
            console.log(WebMURL); // prints the blob url
            var recordedBlob = Video.RTC.getBlob();
            console.log(recordedBlob); // prints undefined
            Video.save(recordedBlob);
        });
    },
    save: function(recordedBlob){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('mode', 'getusermedia');
        formData.append('blob', recordedBlob);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        };
        request.open('POST', rootPath+'ajax/processVideo.php');
        request.send(formData);
    }
};
```

And this is how the code is run inline in my script:

```
var playerId = 'cam-'+t+'-'+click[1]+'-'+click[2];
Video.init(playerId);

if(Video.media){
    document.getElementById('stop-'+playerId).onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        Video.stop();
    };

    Video.media(Video.RtcOpts, Video.success, Video.error);
}else{
    //fallback
}
```

Comment: How did you get the blob URL to begin with? What you should be uploading is the file blob you got. ``blob:`` is a blob URL by the way, not a data URL.

Comment: Ah, I just found the documentation. ``var recordedBlob = recordRTC.getBlob();`` should help you a lot.

Comment: See, that's what I thought. However, recordedBlob is always undefined. I'm going to update the question to include some example code.

Comment: http://recordrtc.org/MRecordRTC.html check that link for guidance. The line ``Video.RTC = new MRecordRTC(stream);`` should be replaced with ``Video.RTC = new MRecordRTC(); Video.RTC.addStream(stream);`` from what I can tell, though I've never really used this so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Good catch, but no change. I'm wondering if it might be a bug in the MRecordRTC class somewhere. I just hate to have to worry about using RecordRTC and having to aggregate the audio and video streams into one.

Comment: Yeah good luck. I know JavaScript but this is way too specific for my knowledge to be able to apply or help. At this point if I were you I'd poke around the source code and try to find out how the class interacts with usermedia streams and the web audio API and look for things that don't look implemented correctly.

Comment: Or if you're lazy, open an issue report on their github project and make them look for the problem. Be sure to at least isolate the few lines of code that are causing the problem though. In your case, the library function that returns ``undefined`` instead of a ``Blob``.

Answer (score 1):

Using `var recordedBlob = recordRTC.getBlob();`, try this following snippet:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    fd = new FormData();
xhr.open("POST", "/submit.php", true);
fd.append("video", recordedBlob);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // xhr.statusCode === 200 means it worked
});
xhr.send(fd);
```

PHP (I'm really rusty) `$_POST["video"]` should contain the blob.